# Trie Data Structure Implementation in C++11 using Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, trie

This implementation is part of my open source project [forest](https://github.com/xorz57/forest).

I wrote the following header file to implement a trie data structure that supports inserting and searching strings consisting of 26 lower-case letters of the English alphabet. I am looking forward to hearing your opinion about this implementation and any suggestions/fixes you may have.

```
/**
 * @file trie.h
 */

#ifndef TRIE_H
#define TRIE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

/**
 * @brief The forest library namespace
 */
namespace forest {
  namespace trie {
    /**
     * @brief trie node struct
     */
    struct node {
      std::shared_ptr<node> children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
      bool end;
      /**
       * @brief Constructor of a trie node
       */
      node() {
        this->end = false; 
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
          this->children[i] = NULL;
        }
      }
    };
    /**
     * @brief trie class
     */
    class tree {
    private:
      std::shared_ptr<node> root;
    public:
      tree() {
              root = std::make_shared<node>();
      }
      /**
       * @brief Inserts the given key into the trie
       * @param key The key to be inserted
       * @return void
       */
      void insert(const std::string &key) {
        std::shared_ptr<node> n = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
          int index = key[i] - 'a';
          if (n->children[index] == nullptr) {
            n->children[index] = std::make_shared<node>();
          }
          n = n->children[index];
        }
        n->end = true;
      }
      /**
       * @brief Searches for the given key in the trie
       * @param key The key to be inserted
       * @return true if key exists in the trie and false otherwise
       */
      const bool search(const std::string &key) {
        std::shared_ptr<node> n = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
          int index = key[i] - 'a';
          if (n->children[index] == nullptr) {
            return false;
          }
          n = n->children[index];
        }
        return (n != nullptr && n->end == true);
      }
    };
  }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your include guard might clash with another file.  After all, you used an outer namespace because the name is not unique enough; the same is true for the header.  Suggest you use a UUID for that, and also `#pragma once` .  (Personally, I chose to use the pragma only with the idea that if I ever need guards they can be mechanically generated, all *correctly*.  But all the major platforms take the pragma so I never needed guards.)

---

```
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26
```

Noooo…  Don’t use `#define` for simple constants, especially in a header file!

---

Let’s look at your `node` constructor:

(and what's with all the `this->` on every member access?)

```
this->end = false;
```

You should not be *assigning* initial values in the constructor.  You should *initialize* things.  Here, you can simply use an inline initializer on the data member declaration, and be done with it.

```
// data member
bool end = false;
```

Continuing with the node constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) {
      this->children[i] = NULL;
```

Wow!  Lots to go over here.

First, don’t use `NULL`.  Not ever!  If you are writing in C++11, it is dead and should be forgotten about.

Second, don’t write legacy `for` loops to go over a collection.  Use the range-for form instead.

```
for (auto el : children)
    el.reset();
```

Third, don’t write loops at all if you can [use algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

```
std::fill (std::begin(children), std::end(children), nullptr);
```

but I don’t like the need to give two separate points like that when I just want the whole thing.  The std algorithms are behind in this respect.  But, we have Boost as a proving ground for library stuff that we want to add to the standard or simply make commonly used:  (see [doc page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/fill.html))

```
boost::fill (children, nullptr);
```

But… just don't!  A `shared_ptr` is automatically initialized to the empty state, which means the constructor is already doing this before the body of your code is run!

So, add the inline initializer for `end`, and then *delete the entire constructor*.

---

Now look at the constructor for `tree`.

Same thing:  don’t *assign* in the body, but *initialize* members.  The inline member init will work fine here.

```
// data member of tree
std::shared_ptr<node> root = std::make_shared<node>();
```

and then delete the whole `tree()` constructor function.

---

tree::insert

In C++ (unlike C) the style is to put the * or & of the type with the type, not the name being defined.  So write `string& name` not `string &name`.

Use `auto` (almost everywhere).

```
auto n = root;
```

For the `for` loop, the same comments as before.  Stop thinking of index numbers into an array or other collection that then need to be subscripted.  Rather, think about *iterator positions* in any kind of collection, or constructs that do the traversal and just give you a reference to the item to work on.

So, no `i`.

```
for (auto ch : key) {
```

Don’t compare pointers (or smart pointers) against null.  They have a truth value that works for this directly.

Remember you can make a reference (an alias) to any part of your data, so don’t repeat `children[index]` three times.

```
auto& slot = n->children[index];
if (!slot)  slot = make_shared<node>();
n= slot;
```

---

Similar for `search`.
Returning a `const bool` doesn’t do anything; just return `bool`.
At the end of that function, testing against `true` is just silly.  It is already a `bool`!  What value does it hold?  `true`.

Also, not explicitly testing against `nullptr` here helps you see how the idiom works well for *guarding* the real test:

```
return n && n->end;
```

Oh, and don’t put redundant parenthesis around return values.

---

BTW, your algorithm and approach is quite sound.  It’s only the C++ language fluency and idioms that I commented on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to review my source code (I hope you did not bleach your eyes while reading it :P). I read through all the recommendations and explanations you gave me above and implemented nearly everything you said. LOL that const bool was propably written around 4:00 AM :P .

Comment: 4AM is a great time for programming.  Bleach — I've seen _far_ worse, professionally.  You can post a follow-up on a fresh Q and refer back to this one, to show your next revision.

Comment: Here is the [latest source code](https://github.com/xorz57/forest/blob/master/include/forest/trie.h) after your recommendations. I don't know if it's a good idea to post a new question with the better source code (i don't know if it violates the rules). Let me know what you think.

Comment: [seems to be](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191098/temperature-unit-conversion-c-f-k-in-c-follow-up/191214) normal to do so. I’ve also seen comments advising to do so (and not update the code in the question once answers appear).

Answer (score 1):

#### Use of `shared_ptr`

Be wary of `std::shared_ptr` if you're not sharing the data. Shared pointers are not free, compared to `std::unique_ptr` and raw pointers copying a shared pointer is fairly expensive. Usually you will want to use a `shared_ptr` when you are expressing shared ownership of the data. The nodes are never exposed to the outside of your trie, using `unique_ptr` should be sufficient here.

Given `std::unique_ptr<Node> root` and using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children` in the node you'd rewrite your loop to something like this:

```
    node* n = root.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
      int index = key[i] - 'a';
      if (n->children[index] == nullptr) {
        n->children[index] = std::make_unique<node>();
      }
      n = n->children[index].get();
    }
```

#### Warnings

Compiling with `-Wall` on shows two warnings both with regard to `key.length()` which returns `size_t` and not `int`.

#### `ALPHABET_SIZE`

Ass @JDługosz said, don't `#define` that, you are putting that into global scope, you can use a local member variable in the `trie` structure that is where it's being used. If you need it out side, make it public, you can also make it static then it becomes accessible as `Trie::Alphabet_Size`.

Depending on your target language, confining yourself to ASCII characters might not be a very future proof way to implement this datastructure.

#### Comments

It's nice to attempt documentation, but look at what some of your documentation says:

```
  ...
  /**
  * @brief trie node struct
  */
  struct node {
  ...
```

It's mainly repeating what the code already says, the only word in that documentation block that adds any kind of information is `trie` and it's really implied by the namespace. Saying nothing would probably been better here. Try say something that the code doesn't express.

#### Naming

Your `trie` is named `tree` well technically it's named `trie::tree`, while you alread have a namespace `forest` why not just call it `trie`, it will save generations of programmers from having to type another namespace label, and it will let people write `using forest::trie` and not mistake it with the `tree` you would have to put under `forest::redblack::tree` if you keep your naming scheme going.